# Error starting Apache Drill in Embedded Mode on Windows 10

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to start Apache Drill 1.10 in Embedded Mode on Windows 10 x64 (with Oracle JVM 1.8.0_131). When launching the command

```
sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"
```

I get the following:

```
Error during udf area creation [/C:/Users/<user>/drill/udf/registry] on file system [file:///] (state=,code=0)
```

So, after some googling, I have changed the drill-override.conf file this way:

```
drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",
  zk.connect: "localhost:2181",
  udf: {
    # number of retry attempts to update remote function registry
    # if registry version was changed during update
    retry-attempts: 10,
    directory: {
      # Override this property if custom file system should be used to create remote directories
      # instead of default taken from Hadoop configuration
      fs: "file:///",
      # Set this property if custom absolute root should be used for remote directories
      root: "/c:/work"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have checked the following:

- proper permission set on the folder
- console started as an Administrator

But I still get the same error:

```
Error during udf area creation [/c:/work/drill/udf/registry] on file system [file:///] (state=,code=0)
```

I can't disable UDF since I don't have an active connection.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

Seems to be related to ownership of the folders, as per [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-5101) link.
Details of the solution from the link are quoted as follows

> Run these commands before the first time you are running sqlline.bat.
>
> mkdir %userprofile%\drill
>
> mkdir %userprofile%\drill\udf
>
> mkdir %userprofile%\drill\udf\registry
>
> mkdir %userprofile%\drill\udf\tmp
>
> mkdir %userprofile%\drill\udf\staging
>
> takeown /R /F %userprofile%\drill

Comment: Wasted countless hours on getting this to work on a Friday afternoon, your tip worked like charm and fixed it in 30 seconds. Thanks a lot!